# authenticate to Alfresco repository using siteminderToken

Tags: alfresco, siteminder

I have authenticated using Siteminder & I have obtained accessToken.

Now there is another application that comes under the scope of same application.

I want to use Alfresco there without any need of further sign-up. Basically I want to implement single sign on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Siteminder, but sso is possible in alfresco.
You'll have to look at how the authentication subsystem work. You'll find the configuration under alfresco.war\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\subsystems\Authentication\ you can redefine them under /shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/

Things exist for:

- alfrescoNtlm (alfresco's own mechanism)
- kerberos
- ldap
- ldap-ad
- passtrhu
- external <- this on is a good candidate for you

With external you can tell aflresco to trust what comes from an url. You'll find information here http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/auth-external-intro.html or there http://smasue.github.io/alfresco-external-sso

I hope this helps